# Sorting a list of enumerations

Tags: c#, list, sorting, struct, enums

So I have an enumeration

```
public enum CardValue
{
    Deuce = 2, Three, Four.... //And so on..
}
```

Then I also have a structure

```
public struct Card
{
   public CardSuit S;
   public CardValue CV;

   public Card(CardSuit Suit, CardValue value)
   {
       S = suit;
       CV = value;
   }
}
```

Then I populated my list with the some card values (all random). I am trying to sort them so I can have the value from highest to lowest, and I can't seem to get it right. What I am trying is:

```
List<Card> Hand1 = new List<Deck>();
Hand1.Sort(CardVale.Ace => CardValue.Duece)
```

I was just wondering what is wrong. If anyone would be able to help me that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort takes an expression that converts the class in list to the property you want to sort by

`Hand1.Sort(x=>x.CV)`

An expression like `x=>x.CV` is the equivelent of

`private static CardValue GetFieldToSortOn(Card x)
{
    return x.CV;
}`

Comment: I did get it to work, and I used a slight variant of this code. Thank you. I just need to wait to accept your answer.